# How to get WooCommerce attribute label and id from slug name in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an attribute:

- Name(label): Box Size
- Slag: box-size

I tried this code:

```
$attribute_slug = 'pa_box-size'; 

// Get the term object based on the attribute slug
$term = get_term_by('slug', $attribute_slug, 'pa');

if ($term) {
   $attribute_label = $term->name; // Attribute label
   $attribute_id = $term->term_id; // Attribute ID

   // Output the attribute label and ID
   echo 'Attribute Slug: ' . $attribute_slug . '<br>';
   echo 'Attribute Label: ' . $attribute_label . '<br>';
   echo 'Attribute ID: ' . $attribute_id;
} else {
   echo 'Attribute not found: ' . $attribute_slug;
}
```

But got always "Attribute not found: pa_box-size".

Comment: Because the taxonomy isn't `pa` it would be `pa_box-size` and the `slug` would be `box-size`.

Comment: with get_term_by('slug', 'box-size', 'pa_box-size'); No change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this:

```
$output = '<ul style="list-style:none;">';

// Loop through all Woocommerce product attributes
foreach (wc_get_attribute_taxonomies() as $attribute) {
  $attribute_label = $attribute->attribute_label;  // Product attribute name
  $attribute_slug = $attribute->attribute_name;    // Product attribute slug
  $attribute_id = $attribute->attribute_id;        // Attribute ID

  $output.= '<li class="'.$attribute_slug.'" data-id="'.$attribute_id.'">'
                .$attribute_label.'</li>';
}
// Output
echo $output.'</ul>';
```

Source: [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/346439/get-woocommerce-product-attribute-taxonomies-in-a-sql-query-on-wordpress-databas#answer-346442)

So I will just need an IF statement to check a specific attribute.

Answer (score -1):

```
You can try this code.

$attribute_slug = 'color'; // Replace with your attribute slug

$product_attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

foreach ($product_attributes as $product_attribute) {
    if ($product_attribute->attribute_name === $attribute_slug) {
        $attribute_label = $product_attribute->attribute_label;
        $attribute_id = $product_attribute->attribute_id;

        echo 'Attribute Label: ' . $attribute_label . '<br>';
        echo 'Attribute ID: ' . $attribute_id;

        break;
    }
}
```